# inconsistent require_once behaviour in same folder

Tags: php

I have two files in the same folder, let's call them `file1` and `file2`. Each of them use the same path to an include file called `dbgeneral.php`. They each then call the function `admin_page_init()` to check session information and bar access to non admins. One of the files works fine, however the other throws up an error on the require. If I copy paste the included file into the file which throws the error it works fine. If I include a copy of the file from a different folder it works fine. For some reason it refuses to find the file if it is in the same folder. I can use `file_exists()` and it returns positive. As far as I know there is no reason for this behaviour.

```
Folder Structure:
html/
    / dbgeneral.php
    / file1.php
    / file2.php

code:
require_once 'dbgeneral.php';
admin_page_init();
```

Also note that I tried using the superglobal $_SERVER to acquire the real absolute path. **Also, this works on my local test server, but does not work on my web host.**

Comment: Can you show ALL of the require code, and error messages?

Comment: File1 and file2 each have the same 2 lines. In fact many files all have the same two lines. For some reason only one of the files has an issue with the require statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include_once 'dbgeneral.php';
include_once 'file1.php';
include_once 'file2.php';
```

This will work. If it does not, it will show you an error as to why it did not work; require will not show you an error in the same fashion.